# I am having this kind of error while doing mass delete

Tags: module, magento2.3.5-p1

I am facing this error while doing mass delete action in magento 2.3.5.

{"Invalid method delete","1":"#1}

Please anyone have idea please Share with me.
Thank you In Advance.

Comment: Delete what where

Comment: when i am going to massdelete then it will show me this error

Comment: need more information, what entity are you trying to delete? Please check also your logs

Comment: I am developing custom module for contact information and i want to add,edit,massdelete contact details from backend using ui components.